# Zip with sparse array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have two arrays, one of them is sparse. I'd like to perform what is essentially an *outer join* on them.

```
const a = ['a', 'b']
a[3] = 'c'
// a is Array(4) [ "a", "b", <1 empty slot>, "c" ]

R.zipSparse([1, 2, 3, 4], a)
// expected output: [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, undefined], [4, 'c']]
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this functionally in Ramda or plain Javascript welcome.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4].map((el, index) => ([el, a[index]]))`

Comment: That is precisely what `R.zip` returns.  Are you looking for something different?

Comment: More specifically, `R.zip` combines things up to the smaller of the reported lengths of the inputs.  Those both have length `4`, so it will return a four-element array in response.  Index `3` will contain `[3, undefined]`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet oh my god you're right. I was acturally trying to solve a different issue, but you are correct that zip acts the way I'm envisioning. Could you formulate this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function zipSparse(arr, join) {
  return arr.map((i, index) => [i, join[index]])
}
```

To explain what is going on here we're using the map iterator and looping over each item in arr and then joining the same item at the index of the second array join

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This is the way to go in pure javascript.

Comment: gotta love es6 :)

Comment: Nothing ES6-specific here.  In ES6's arrow syntax, this would be shorter: `(arr, join) => arr.map((i, index) => [i, join[index]])`.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually the behavior of `R.zip`.

More specifically, `R.zip` combines things up to the smaller of the reported lengths of the inputs. Those both have length `4`, so it will return a four-element array in response. Index `3` will contain `[3, undefined]`.

Of course this is quite easy to write yourself, without Ramda, as the answer from @JoeWarner and the comment from @dsfq show.